# How can I calculate value of an expression in a separate process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code that creates 6 processes and passes objects to the parent process through the pipe, in such case value of the expression 2 ** 320000 is being calculated in the parent process, not in the child processes.

How can I calculate it in the child process and then pass the result to the parent process?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe


def child(pipe, no):
    for i in range(5):
        #str(2 ** 320000) # It works this way
        pipe.send([no, i, 2 ** 320000])
    pipe.send('done')
    pipe.close()
    print('child %s close pipe' % no)


def parent():
    procs = 6
    pipes = []
    for i in range(procs):
        parent_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()
        process = Process(target=child, args=(child_pipe, i))
        pipes.append((parent_pipe, child_pipe))
        process.start()

    exit_flag = [False] * procs

    while False in exit_flag:
        for pipe in pipes:

            index = pipes.index(pipe)
            if exit_flag[index]:
                continue

            data = pipe[0].recv()
            if data == 'done':
                exit_flag[index] = True
                continue
            print('parent got: %s' % data)
    print('parent exiting...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent()
```

Comment: Why do you want to calculate 5 times the same value?

Comment: I just study the module and came across such a problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pool of 6 workers:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def child(no):
    print('Child {0}'.format(no))
    return 2 ** 320000

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(6)
    results = p.map(child, list(range(5)))
    print(results)
```

The `map` method is similar to the built in `map` function: it applies a function to a list of values (here there are 5 values).